# Debugging airflow tasks using airflow test vs using DebugExecutor

Tags: debugging, testing, airflow

I'm searching for best way to run/debug tasks and dags in my IDE. I see that there are two ways of doing this. I can run `airflow test` command in debug mode for particular dag and optionally task. Other way is to use `DebugExecutor` and run particular dag. I see that both ways require that Airflow database is up and running and that all pools are configured (probably queues as well). My questions are:

1. What is the main difference between these two?
2. Does `airflow test` uses `DebugExecutor` under the hood?
3. Is there a way to run/debug dags and tasks without running Airflow database and creating dependent pools and queues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the main difference between these two?

Debug Executor runs a full DAG Run so you can test the trigger rules.
`airflow test` command run only one task.

This is even clearer in Airflow 2.0. We have separate commands:

- `airflow dags test` - starts one DAG Run with `DebugExecutor`.
- `airflow tasks test` - starts one tasks.

> Does airflow test uses `DebugExecutor` under the hood?

No. If you use `DebugExecutor` then you need to run full scheduler. If you use the `airflow task` command, only code that is being executed by worker is executed.

> Is there a way to run/debug dags and tasks without running Airflow database and creating dependent pools and queues?

You can load a DAG with `DagBag` and then call the execute method of your task.

```py
from airflow.model.dagbag import DagBag
dag_file_path = "/home/test-user/dags/dag-file.py"
dagbag = DagBag(dag_folder=dag_file_path)
dagbag.dags['test-dag-id'].task_dict['task-id'].execute({})
```

Comment: Great, thanks! So, this way of running tasks is something similar we would use for unit tests.